# How to get credit card details using nfc in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to ask if its possible to read credit card details using flutter. I have implemented something that can detect the nfc from the application but I can't find a way to get the credit card's data like NAME, CARD NUMBER and EXPIRY DATE. I want to know if its possible to do it with flutter or shall I need to use java - kotlin to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Reading of Credit Card credentials like card number or expiration can be read out using the IsoDep class by doing a "question & answer" challenge but this class is not accessable on IOS so you will end up in using the Android-part of a Flutter library that is programmed in Java/Kotlin. B.t.w.: as the card holder's name would be a security risk it is no longer part of the data available using NFC - it is "just" printed on the card same to a card verification code (CVC).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to do it using only flutter and you are right I got all the data except the card holdername and CVV or CVC. It was weird at first because the tag 5f20 was there but it was just a "/" had to do a bit of research on EVM book to find out it is private now.

Comment: hello, @KonstantinosRotsidis did you write an article on how you did this, can you direct me?, since you were unable to get the cvv/cvc what did you do to implement contact less payment?